# How to display HTML content in windows phone?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

how to display my html content in my application.how to use htmltextblock? please help me frnd..i stucked with one week for this problem...my xml document description tag has html content how to bind that tag to my application

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean, please?  Where is the HTML source coming from?  Can you give an example of your incoming XML?

Comment: Html source in my xml description tag

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could probably make use of a WebBrowser control to show this content.  An example of showing data from a string in this control from code behind would be as follows...

```
webBrowser1.NavigateToString("<html><body><h1>Description</h1><p>This is a description, set from code</p></body></html>");
```

I am tempted to downvote myself for using invalid markup in the HTML, but that seems a bit harsh, doesn't it? ;)

Anyway, if you want to bind to a property of a model, you will have to do some extra work to set the bindings.  [This blog post](http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/binding-html-to-the-web-browser-control) does a good job of explaining how to add a dependency property that you may use to bind to HTML strings in your models.

Comment: Close the final HTML tag, Pandora! :D

Comment: how to store HTML content into variable

Comment: how to use XAML Attached properties

Comment: @Malar - Read the blog post I linked to in the answer.

Comment: @ZombieSheep I am using that NavigateToString and it is work fine, but only for WP8.1 the problem is with WP8.0, do you have any solution?