# How to bind html content

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I'm new to windows phone application development.currently i'm doing xml reader project.in my project display the xml description content.i used textblock to display the content.but HTML tag not supported.please help alternative for textblock.how to bind

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display HTML content in windows phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928792/how-to-display-html-content-in-windows-phone)

Comment: If you don't like the answers to a question you asked, please don't start a new one with identical requirements.  Thanks

Comment: @ZombieSheep looks like I wasted my time giving an answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you have HTML content, the most appropriate tool for viewing it is a `WebBrowser` control. This will render arbitrary HTML, it will also fetch images over HTTP etc ...